# Varnish+Nginx+Magento almost like one request per second

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, cache, varnish, magento

I have been on the administrative side of a small magento 2 developers team.
For the problem i am about to share you can ask for a demo page and check it out aswell you find the information shared lacking.
So.

They have been setting all their magento 1 installations behind nginx and php-fpm7.1

I got huge troubles debugging Varnish since it requires a great understanding of header fields and Varnish states.

So they decided to start doing demos with magento 2 but we noticed that the performance compared to magento1(same stack) is terrible.
Nginx could server 3k requests per second with magento1.9.2 and there is a decline to 50 requests per second.
Ofc course Magento 2.2.1 full page cache is not working so they asked of me to setup Varnish, as recommended.

**EDIT** : 
*Title changed to reflect the problem.*

> It was about checkout and admin panel only.I was wrong. The problem is
>   not actually only on these places. The problem is everywhere and shows
>   up for almost a second after a succesful request is made. If i load
>   the landing page 5 times in a row only the 1st time will get a 200 and
>   the rest a 502.

**The Setup**:

- Nginx serves at ports 80/443 and passes all traffic to Varnish at port 6081(def port).
- Varnish works with Magento generated VCL and if needed redirects to Backend at 8080.

**The problem:**
*See the edit above.*

<del>Typical backend jobs, like cache flush, and www.mymagento.com/Checkout/ lead to 502.
Whenever i try to add something to a cart, and go to checkout i get a 502.
Whenever  flush the cache or re-index data i get a 502.</del>

**What does nginx report on the time of event?**

```
2017/12/14 16:16:08 [error] 17110#17110: *236271 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 91.140.10.184, server: dom.com, request: "GET / HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:6081/", host: "dom.com"
2017/12/14 16:16:08 [info] 17110#17110: *236323 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while sending to client, client: 127.0.0.1, server: dom.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.0", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9007", host: "dom.com"
2017/12/14 16:16:08 [error] 17110#17110: *236271 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 91.140.10.184, server: dom.com, request: "GET / HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:6081/", host: "dom.com"
2017/12/14 16:16:09 [error] 17110#17110: *236271 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 91.140.10.184, server: dom.com, request: "GET / HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:6081/", host: "dom.com"
2017/12/14 16:16:09 [info] 17110#17110: *236332 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while sending to client, client: 127.0.0.1, server: dom.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.0", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9007", host: "dom.com"
2017/12/14 16:16:09 [error] 17110#17110: *236271 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 91.140.10.184, server: dom.com, request: "GET / HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:6081/", host: "dom.com"
2017/12/14 16:16:09 [error] 17110#17110: *236271 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 91.140.10.184, server: dom.com, request: "GET / HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:6081/", host: "dom.com"
```

**Varnish log**

```
*   << BeReq    >> 294951
-   Begin          bereq 294950 pass
-   Timestamp      Start: 1513009334.530160 0.000000 0.000000
-   BereqMethod    GET
-   BereqURL       /checkout/
-   BereqProtocol  HTTP/1.0
-   BereqHeader    Host: www.mymagento.com
-   BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-Host: www.mymagento.com
-   BereqHeader    X-Real-IP: 37.6.210.242
-   BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-Proto: https
-   BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-Port: 443
-   BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-Proto: https
-   BereqHeader    Content-Length: 0
-   BereqHeader    user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:57.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/57.0
-   BereqHeader    accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
-   BereqHeader    accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.5
-   BereqHeader    accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
-   BereqHeader    referer: https://www.mymagento.com/catalog/product/view/id/3350/s/1510911799-kalson-elafaki-mayro/category/41/
-   BereqHeader    upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
-   BereqHeader    cookie: _ga=GA1.2.2063407653.1510934108; __zlcmid=jpgwnJ1tBFQDKV; intercom-session-xmx5ec9n=dWh5bmg4Y29Sb2FZUW9ybEN6YzJSVGpycE1CZkQvK0hhZnFJYmhNOTJmems0d3p3NkgvSWNORmVVcFRneTVFMy0tOG5JTXJ3aHFYRFlnaTUvbmM4Z1BQZz09--5a2e1ecdcaf4577b3b82a02ad1271c00b50931b1
-   BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-For: 37.6.210.242, 127.0.0.1
-   BereqHeader    X-Varnish: 294951
-   VCL_call       BACKEND_FETCH
-   VCL_return     fetch
-   Backend        14 default default(127.0.0.1,,8080)
-   Timestamp      Bereq: 1513009334.530267 0.000107 0.000107
-   Timestamp      Beresp: 1513009334.720461 0.190301 0.190194
-   BerespProtocol HTTP/1.1
-   BerespStatus   200
-   BerespReason   OK
-   BerespHeader   Server: nginx
-   BerespHeader   Date: Mon, 11 Dec 2017 16:22:14 GMT
-   BerespHeader   Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
-   BerespHeader   Connection: close
-   BerespHeader   Vary: Accept-Encoding
-   BerespHeader   X-Powered-By: PHP/7.1
-   BerespHeader   Set-Cookie: form_key=HitLxJK4OFvkFpFq; expires=Mon, 11-Dec-2017 17:22:14 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/; domain=mage2secure.magedeploy.com
-   BerespHeader   Set-Cookie: form_key=HitLxJK4OFvkFpFq; expires=Mon, 11-Dec-2017 17:22:14 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/; domain=mage2secure.magedeploy.com
-   BerespHeader   Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=suasda12321sgrb840ebodav186; expires=Mon, 11-Dec-2017 17:22:14 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/; domain=www.mymagento.com; secure; HttpOnly
-   BerespHeader   Set-Cookie: X-Magento-Vary=7f0ec19209469e9c448407b53fa5e756e55a0200; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
-   BerespHeader   Pragma: no-cache
-   BerespHeader   Cache-Control: max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-cache, no-store
-   BerespHeader   Expires: Sun, 11 Dec 2016 16:22:14 GMT
-   BerespHeader   X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
-   BerespHeader   X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
-   BerespHeader   X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
-   TTL            RFC 0 -1 -1 1513009335 1513009335 1513009334 1481473334 0
-   VCL_call       BACKEND_RESPONSE
-   TTL            VCL -1 259200 0 1513009335
-   TTL            VCL 120 259200 0 1513009335
-   VCL_return     deliver
-   BerespHeader   Content-Encoding: gzip
-   Storage        malloc Transient
-   ObjProtocol    HTTP/1.1
-   ObjStatus      200
-   ObjReason      OK
-   ObjHeader      Server: nginx
-   ObjHeader      Date: Mon, 11 Dec 2017 16:22:14 GMT
-   ObjHeader      Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
-   ObjHeader      Vary: Accept-Encoding
-   ObjHeader      X-Powered-By: PHP/7.0.26
-   ObjHeader      Set-Cookie: form_key=HitLxJK4OFvkFpFq; expires=Mon, 11-Dec-2017 17:22:14 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/; domain=mage2secure.magedeploy.com
-   ObjHeader      Set-Cookie: form_key=HitLxJK4OFvkFpFq; expires=Mon, 11-Dec-2017 17:22:14 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/; domain=mage2secure.magedeploy.com
-   ObjHeader      Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=su53asdad223sgrb83dav186; expires=Mon, 11-Dec-2017 17:22:14 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/; domain=mage2secure.magedeploy.com; secure; HttpOnly
-   ObjHeader      Set-Cookie: X-Magento-Vary=7f0ec19209469e9c448407b53fa5e756e55a0200; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
-   ObjHeader      Pragma: no-cache
-   ObjHeader      Cache-Control: max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-cache, no-store
-   ObjHeader      Expires: Sun, 11 Dec 2016 16:22:14 GMT
-   ObjHeader      X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
-   ObjHeader      X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
-   ObjHeader      X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
-   ObjHeader      Content-Encoding: gzip
-   Fetch_Body     4 eof -
-   VSL            flush
-   End            synth
```

**Varnish VCL**

```
vcl 4.0; import std;
# The minimal Varnish version is 4.0 For SSL offloading, pass the following header in your proxy server or load balancer: 'X-Forwarded-Proto:
# https'
backend default {
    .host = "localhost";
    .port = "8080";
    .first_byte_timeout = 900s;
    .probe = {
        .url = "/health_check.php";
        .timeout = 2s;
        .interval = 5s;
        .window = 10;
        .threshold = 5;
   }
}
acl purge {
    "localhost";
}
sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.method == "PURGE") {
        if (client.ip !~ purge) {
            return (synth(405, "Method not allowed"));
        }
        # To use the X-Pool header for purging varnish during automated deployments, make sure the X-Pool header has been added to the response in
        # your backend server config. This is used, for example, by the capistrano-magento2 gem for purging old content from varnish during it's
        # deploy routine.
        if (!req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern && !req.http.X-Pool) {
            return (synth(400, "X-Magento-Tags-Pattern or X-Pool header required"));
        }
        if (req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern) {
          ban("obj.http.X-Magento-Tags ~ " + req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern);
        }
        if (req.http.X-Pool) {
          ban("obj.http.X-Pool ~ " + req.http.X-Pool);
        }

        return (synth(200, "Purged"));
    }
    if (req.method != "GET" &&
        req.method != "HEAD" &&
        req.method != "PUT" &&
        req.method != "POST" &&
        req.method != "TRACE" &&
        req.method != "OPTIONS" &&
        req.method != "DELETE") {
          /* Non-RFC2616 or CONNECT which is weird. */
          #was pi pe
          return (pass);
    }
    # We only deal with GET and HEAD by default
    if (req.method != "GET" && req.method != "HEAD") {
        return (pass);
    }
    # Bypass shopping cart, checkout and search requests
    if (req.url ~ "/checkout" || req.url ~ "/catalogsearch") {
        return (pass);
    }

    # Bypass health check requests
    if (req.url ~ "/health_check.php") {
        return (pass);
    }
    # Set initial grace period usage status
    set req.http.grace = "none";
    # normalize url in case of leading HTTP scheme and domain
    set req.url = regsub(req.url, "^http[s]?://", "");
    # collect all cookies
    std.collect(req.http.Cookie);
    # Compression filter. See https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/FAQ/Compression
    if (req.http.Accept-Encoding) {
        if (req.url ~ "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|gz|tgz|bz2|tbz|mp3|ogg|swf|flv)$") {
            # No point in compressing these
            unset req.http.Accept-Encoding;
        } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "gzip") {
            set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "gzip";
        } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "deflate" && req.http.user-agent !~ "MSIE") {
            set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "deflate";
        } else {
            # unkown algorithm
            unset req.http.Accept-Encoding;
        }
    }
    # Remove Google gclid parameters to minimize the cache objects
    set req.url = regsuball(req.url,"\?gclid=[^&]+$",""); # strips when QS = "?gclid=AAA"
    set req.url = regsuball(req.url,"\?gclid=[^&]+&","?"); # strips when QS = "?gclid=AAA&foo=bar"
    set req.url = regsuball(req.url,"&gclid=[^&]+",""); # strips when QS = "?foo=bar&gclid=AAA" or QS = "?foo=bar&gclid=AAA&bar=baz"
    # Static files caching
    if (req.url ~ "^/(pub/)?(media|static)/") {
        # Static files should not be cached by default
#        return (hash);
        # But if you use a few locales and don't use CDN you can enable caching static files by commenting previous line (#return (pass);) and
        #uncommenting next 3 lines
        unset req.http.Https;
        unset req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto;
        unset req.http.Cookie;
    }
    return (hash);
}

sub vcl_hash {
    if (req.http.cookie ~ "X-Magento-Vary=") {
        hash_data(regsub(req.http.cookie, "^.*?X-Magento-Vary=([^;]+);*.*$", "\1"));
    }
    # For multi site configurations to not cache each other's content
    if (req.http.host) {
        hash_data(req.http.host);
    } else {
        hash_data(server.ip);
    }
    # To make sure http users don't see ssl warning
    if (req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto) {
        hash_data(req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto);
    }
    if (req.http.user-agent ~ "(?i)iPhone") {
        hash_data("8");
    } elsif (req.http.user-agent ~ "(?i)iPod") {
        hash_data("8");
    } elsif (req.http.user-agent ~ "(?i)BlackBerry") {
        hash_data("8");
    } elsif (req.http.user-agent ~ "(?i)Palm") {
        hash_data("8");
    } elsif (req.http.user-agent ~ "(?i)Googlebot\-Mobile") {
        hash_data("8");
    } elsif (req.http.user-agent ~ "(?i)Windows Mobile") {
        hash_data("8");
    } elsif (req.http.user-agent ~ "(?i)Android") {
        hash_data("8");
    } elsif (req.http.user-agent ~ "(?i)Opera") {
        hash_data("8");
    }
}
sub vcl_backend_response {
    set beresp.grace = 3d;
    if (beresp.http.content-type ~ "text") {
        set beresp.do_esi = true;
    }
    if (bereq.url ~ "\.js$" || beresp.http.content-type ~ "text") {
        set beresp.do_gzip = true;
    }
    # cache only successfully responses and 404s
    if (beresp.status != 200 && beresp.status != 404) {
        set beresp.ttl = 0s;
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
        return (deliver);
    } elsif (beresp.http.Cache-Control ~ "private") {
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
        set beresp.ttl = 86400s;
        return (deliver);
    }
    if (beresp.http.X-Magento-Debug) {
        set beresp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Control = beresp.http.Cache-Control;
    }
    # validate if we need to cache it and prevent from setting cookie
    if (beresp.ttl > 0s && (bereq.method == "GET" || bereq.method == "HEAD")) {
        unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
    }
   # If page is not cacheable then bypass varnish for 2 minutes as Hit-For-Pass
   if (beresp.ttl <= 0s ||
        beresp.http.Surrogate-control ~ "no-store" ||
        (!beresp.http.Surrogate-Control && beresp.http.Vary == "*")) {
        # Mark as Hit-For-Pass for the next 2 minutes
        set beresp.ttl = 120s;
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
    }
    return (deliver);
}

sub vcl_deliver {
    if (resp.http.X-Magento-Debug) {
        if (resp.http.x-varnish ~ " ") {
            set resp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Debug = "HIT";
            set resp.http.Grace = req.http.grace;
        } else {
            set resp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Debug = "MISS";
        }
    } else {
        unset resp.http.Age;
    }
    unset resp.http.X-Magento-Debug;
    unset resp.http.X-Magento-Tags;
    unset resp.http.X-Powered-By;
    unset resp.http.Server;
    unset resp.http.X-Varnish;
    unset resp.http.Via;
    unset resp.http.Link;
}
sub vcl_hit {
    if (obj.ttl >= 0s) {
        # Hit within TTL period
        return (deliver);
    }
    if (std.healthy(req.backend_hint)) {
        if (obj.ttl + 300s > 0s) {
            # Hit after TTL expiration, but within grace period
            set req.http.grace = "normal (healthy server)";
            return (deliver);
        } else {
            # Hit after TTL and grace expiration
            return (fetch);
        }
    } else {
        # server is not healthy, retrieve from cache
        set req.http.grace = "unlimited (unhealthy server)";
        return (deliver);
    }
}
```

**Nginx Site Config**

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name www.mymagento.com;
        location /.well-known/ {
                default_type "text/plain";
                try_files $uri =404;
        }
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
        server_name www.mymagento.com;

        listen 443 ssl http2;
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/magento/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/magento/privkey.pem;

#       port_in_redirect off;

        include https_basic.conf;

        keepalive_timeout 0s;

        location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:6081;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
#        proxy_set_header Ssl-Offloaded "1";
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port 443;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        }
}


server {
        server_name www.mymagento.com;
        listen 8080;

        root /home/magento/public_html/pub/;

        set $HTTPS_FORWARD on;

        index index.php;
        charset UTF-8;
        error_page 404 403 = /errors/404.php;
        expires off;

        # PHP entry point for setup application
        location ~* ^/setup($|/) {
        root    /home/kirakalo/public_html/;
        location ~ ^/setup/index.php {
        #       if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite / /index.php last; }
                fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9007;
                fastcgi_index  index.php;
                fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;

                fastcgi_connect_timeout 600s;
                fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        #        fastcgi_param  PATH_TRANSLATED  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include        fastcgi_params;
#               access_log /var/log/nginx/phpfpmonly-access.log;
        }

        location ~ ^/setup/(?!pub/). {
                deny all;
        }

        location ~ ^/setup/pub/ {
                add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        }
        }

        # PHP entry point for update application
        location ~* ^/update($|/) {
                root /home/kirakalo/public_html/;

            location ~ ^/update/index.php {
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/update/index.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9007;
                fastcgi_index  index.php;

                fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO        $fastcgi_path_info;
        #       fastcgi_param  PATH_TRANSLATED  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include        fastcgi_params;
#               access_log /var/log/nginx/phpfpmonly-access.log;
            }

        # Deny everything but index.php
        location ~ ^/update/(?!pub/). {
                deny all;
        }

        location ~ ^/update/pub/ {
                add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        }
        }

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
        }

        location /pub/ {
                location ~ ^/pub/media/(downloadable|customer|import|theme_customization/.*.xml) {
                        deny all;
                }
                alias /home/kirakalo/public_html/pub/;
                add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";

                location ~ ^/pub/static/version {
                        rewrite ^/pub/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /pub/static/$2 last;
                }

        }


        location /static/ {
        # Uncomment the following line in production mode
#       expires max;

        # Remove signature of the static files that is used to overcome the browser cache
        location ~ ^/static/version {
                rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static/$2 last;
        }

        location ~* .(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|js|css|swf|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2)$ {
                add_header Cache-Control "public";
                add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
                expires +1y;

                if (!-f $request_filename) {
                        rewrite ^/static/?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$1 last;
                }
        }
        location ~* .(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$ {
                add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
                add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
                expires    off;

                if (!-f $request_filename) {
                        rewrite ^/static/?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$1 last;
                }
        }
        if (!-f $request_filename) {
                rewrite ^/static/?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$1 last;
        }
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        }


        location /media/ {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php$is_args$args;

        location ~ ^/media/theme_customization/.*.xml {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~* .(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|js|css|swf|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
#        expires +1y;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php$is_args$args;
    }
    location ~* .(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires    off;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php$is_args$args;
    }
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
}

location /media/customer/ {
    deny all;
}

location /media/downloadable/ {
    deny all;
}

location /media/import/ {
    deny all;
}


location ~ (health_check|op1337|index|get|static|report|404|503).php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9007;   
    fastcgi_param HTTPS $HTTPS_FORWARD;

#    fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
#    fastcgi_connect_timeout 600s;

    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO        $fastcgi_path_info;
    include        fastcgi_params;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/phpfpmonly-access.log;
}

location ~* (.php$|.htaccess$|.git) {
    deny all;
}

}
```

Where is the problem hiding?Is this bad config or maybe related to the teams code?
I am completely new to Varnish and trying to figure this out has become a complete headache.

Edit: Noticed that when i logas a user to the page the cart is filled even if i login/logout.
Note that There is a page that you get to see your cart items.This pages response seems to be "Your cart is empty" even if there is a box on the top that shows items-to-buy and quantities/price.

[cart problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmSDZ.png)

**Note** :
This problem only exists after varnish came in the picture.
As i said already server could handle only up to ~100 requests per second with Magento 2 which is an actually terrible number.

Huge thanks to anyone that will try to help.